# How can I auto populate text in the Comment box in Google+ Share

Tags: javascript, google-plus, sharing

I want to get the user comment from post to Google+ comment box.
this is the code I have built until.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Share demo: Basic page Sharing</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://itexpertsindya.com/projects/maliWeb/maliweb-dev/FrontController/getPostBySelectedDate/2017/04/24" />
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>

    <g:plus action="share"></g:plus>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Got it working after googling few link here is solution in case any one needed.

Comment: Use this link for help => https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive#rendering_the_button_with_javascript